# TeXStudio: select text in pdf viewer

Tags: texstudio

So I'm working with TexStudio in a dual pane view, left my latex code, right the generated PDF in the embedded viewer.

The viewer gives me a scroll option and a zoom option, but I can't select text within the PDF. I seem to recall it being possible with TexMaker, is it also possible in Texstudio?

Comment: Text selection is currently not supported in the internal viewer. Please use an external viewer for this. You can open it directly from the menu bar of the internal viewer.

Answer (score 5):

*Reposted the above comment:*

Text selection is currently not supported in the internal viewer. Please use an external viewer for this. You can open it directly from the menu bar of the internal viewer.

Comment: 7 years later and this is still not possible. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that is not possible in neither compilers, but using 'ABC' (spelling checker) in Texmaker you can select part of text under the PDF viewer without opening the external viewer.

However, to totally solve the issue I highly recommend using WinEdt (text editor) + Sumatra (pdf), which provide almost everything at once e.g., simultaneously syncing codes with the PDF file, selecting the text without external opening PDF files, and inverse searching ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please be more specific about the trick?

Comment: Just to inform that WinEdt is not free.